# convert wierd timestamp format to normal?

Tags: sql, unix, iso8601

2021-05-06T02:21:20.000000Z

So I'm getting timestamps in this ISO 8601 format, but it has that T in the middle instead of space. Not sure how I can script this in SQL select statement to convert to a normal timestamp Numberic:Continuous format.

Select
TimeStamp
,from_unixtime(timestamp)

Comment: What RDBMS (SQL *flavor*) do you use? Date / Time functions are not fully standardized. SQL Server, mySQL, Oracle, ...?

Comment: The `T` is part of an ISO-8601 date+time string, btw. It's supposed to be there and anything claiming to handle the format should understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using MySQL because you referenced the `from_unixtime()` function. That function is for converting a 32-bit integer into a datetime, it cannot parse a string representation of a datetime.

MySQL does have a problem with ISO8601 format. It can sort of read it, but it gets confused at the 'Z':

```
mysql> select '2021-05-06T02:21:20.000000Z' + interval 0 minute as d;
+---------------------+
| d                   |
+---------------------+
| 2021-05-06 02:21:20 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                           |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2021-05-06T02:21:20.000000Z' |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If we were to omit the 'Z', everything is fine:

```
mysql> select '2021-05-06T02:21:20.000000' + interval 0 minute as d;
+---------------------+
| d                   |
+---------------------+
| 2021-05-06 02:21:20 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So just remove the 'Z', either in SQL or before you pass the ISO8601 string value to SQL:

```
mysql> select replace('2021-05-06T02:21:20.000000Z', 'Z', '') + interval 0 minute as d;
+---------------------+
| d                   |
+---------------------+
| 2021-05-06 02:21:20 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```